# Delete multiple data using mapdispatchprops not working in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Try to delete multiple records using api call .

But it delete only first record

```
deleteData = () => 
   {  
        var deleteArray = this.state.deleteArray;
        for(var i=0;i < deleteArray.length;i++){
          
            var name = deleteArray[i].name;
            var id = deleteArray[i].id;
            deleteAPICallDispatch(name,id);  
        }   
   }
```

Dispatch code for call api

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return { 
    deleteAPICallDispatch:(name,id) => dispatch(deleteAPICall(name,id)),
  
  };
};
```

above code calling API only one time instead of multiple times

Comment: Why are you dispatching in a loop, instead of creating the array first, and then calling dispatch? Is that a necessity or just preference?

Comment: yes,need to give id ,name and delete the particular record

Comment: Well I would allow my API to delete multiple, if that is a use case. In that case, I would just dispatch an action with an array of `toBeDeleted` items, and send the array to the back-end. Backend will loop through the array and delete the items.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
deleteData = () => {
  Promise.all(
    this.state.deleteArray.map(({ name, id }) =>
      deleteAPICallDispatch(name, id)
    )
  );
};
```

You could log this.state.deleteArray.length to make sure it is correct.